# C# Selenium 2 Test Canonical Linke

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium 2.0 and I want to test the correct canonical link is being tested. How would I get this using the webdriver in c#?

Something like: `WebDriver.FindElementByName("head").FindElement(By.Rel....`

```
<head>
    <link href="http://www.test.com/canonical" rel="canonical" />
    <link href="/Content/Reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this specifically, but I'd probably approach it like this:

```
// Assume driver is a correctly initialized IWebDriver instance,
// pointed at the page in question
IWebElement head = driver.FindElement(By.TagName, "head");

// Could also use By.XPath here with an appropriate XPath expression like
// FindElement(By.XPath, "./link[@rel='canonical']")
IWebElement link = head.FindElement(By.CssSelector, "link[@rel='canonical']");
```

The only thing I'd caution about is that finding elements under  may be problematic.